# Error after selecting object with Perst for Windows Phone

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0

I have the following situation:

My WP7 app has a login screen, where it executes the following lines of code:

```
var userQuery = DataAccessManager.Instance.Database.Select<LocalUser>(u => _userLogin.Equals(u.Login));  //_userLogin and Login property are strings
var lstUser = userQuery.ToList();
```

In some situation, I need to call the login screen again, where it executes the same method with the same lines of code above. But, in this second time, I get the following error when calling

```
var lstUser = userQuery.ToList();
```

Mobiltec.Atheneum.Common.Utils.Synchronization.AuthHandler+<>c__DisplayClass2.*userLogin
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeFieldInfo.GetValue(Object obj)
   at System.Linq.jvm.ExpressionInterpreter.b*_0(FieldInfo field)
   at System.Linq.jvm.Extensions.OnFieldOrProperty(MemberInfo self, Action`1 onfield, Action`1 onprop)
   at System.Linq.jvm.ExpressionInterpreter.VisitMemberInfo(MemberInfo mi)
   at System.Linq.jvm.ExpressionInterpreter.VisitMemberAccess(MemberExpression member)
   at System.Linq.jvm.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.jvm.ExpressionInterpreter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Linq.jvm.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.jvm.ExpressionInterpreter.Interpret(LambdaExpression lambda, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Linq.jvm.Interpreter.Run(Object[] arg)
   at System.Linq.jvm.Interpreter.FuncRunner[T,TResult](LocalUser arg)
   at Perst.Database.LinqEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Mobiltec.Atheneum.Common.Utils.Synchronization.AuthHandler.Authenticate(String _userLogin, String _password, String *deviceNickname)
   at Mobiltec.Atheneum.Reader.WindowsPhone.Controls.LoginControl.<>c*_DisplayClass4.b__0(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
   at System.Threading.Timer.ring()

Any idea about it?. We have the same class in a Silverlight to Desktop application and I don't know why it's happening with WP7.

**PS1:** The problem doesn't occur with LocalUser class only...it's with any class.

**PS2:** If I use this:

```
var userQuery = DataAccessManager.Instance.Database.Select<LocalUser>(u => "cesarautor@atheneum.com".Equals(u.Login)); //as sample...any dumb string works
```

instead of

```
var userQuery = DataAccessManager.Instance.Database.Select<LocalUser>(u => _userLogin.Equals(u.Login));
```

it works...

Thanks in advance

Comment: From the stack trace and from your PS2, it sounds like the problem is with the _userLogin variable. What is the error you are seeing - what is the exception?

Comment: Hi Stuart. The trace I posted here is all I have available. There's no InnerException. Thus, I tried to use another dummy variable instead of _userLogin, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Also tried "==" instead of ".Equals"...no effect

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, there's no OuterException posted in your question, just a stack trace? The exception type would be helpful. Also, what is the type of _userLogin - is it just a String?

Comment: Sorry, you didn't miss it. It's a FieldAccessException and yes, that's just a string. I also tried comparing longs for test sake, but the same occurs.

Comment: I just checked that
    var userQuery = DataAccessManager.Instance.Database.Select<LocalUser>(string.Empty).Where(u => u.Login == _userLogin);
works, but it doesn't make sense to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a few other references around about Perst and FieldAccessException: e.g. http://forums.mcobject.com/index.php?showtopic=7916

At a guess, this will be caused by the code somehow using trying to use reflection on that expression - as this will works OK inside the less restrictive environment of the Silverlight desktop.

Does it work if you change the _userLogin reference to instead reference a local variable - as this would hopefully require less/different reflection calls

Comment: Thanks for your effort, Stuart. Seems that there's not much to do about it, or at least I couldn't realize that.